# Word lists continuing past normal text

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013

I am having an issue in Word (both 2010 and 2013) where lists are continuing past where there is normal text i.e. something like this:

> 1. asd
> 2. asd
>
> asdasd
>   3. asd

This is a problem that I can solve (mostly) by doing restart numbering.

However, if I wish to switch up the list to say, `1),2)...` if that is a level in the previous list, it will indent to that level, and force the list to continue.

How I make it so that when text autoformatted to be part of a list, that list must start from scratch?

Here is an example of this issue:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8syevhwfx78hztn/example%20word.docx

Comment: As long as Word can't detect the presence of a list right before, then it would always start at 1), unless there is something fishy going there; at that point, an analysis in the Draft mode (or other ones) could help. I actually had the reverse problem (where I wanted to keep the numbering after writing text), my solution to my problem was brute-forcing the process (i.e. telling what number there was).

Comment: I don't know how to fix this issue (that it keeps detecting the old list) or even how it was created (just that it happens somewhat randomly)

Comment: Like I said, try to see the Draft mode, as there you can see the *underlying* structure.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard it looks the same to me, but I think it is missing something. I will take a look at the underlying XML later.

Comment: (As I don't have an English version of Office this might be a translation issue; try all available View modes)

Answer (score 0):

If want the numbered list in your Word document to start at 1, but it keeps starting at 3, even if you select Restart Numbering from the shortcut menu. If I understand your question correctly

Right-click the numbered list.

Click Set Numbering Value.

Select the Start New List button.

In the Set Value text box, type 1 and then click OK.

When you set the Set Value text box to a number, your list will start with that number; when Restart does not start with 1, it's best to check and reset the Set Value text box according to the steps above.

The Set Numbering Value will also correct instances where clicking Continue Numbering will not work -- for example, when you want one list to continue numbering from another above it. Follow these steps to correct this situation:

Right-click the numbered list.

Click Set Numbering Value.

Click to select the Continue From Previous List button and then click OK.

Comment: My issues is that I need to do restart list. I do not want to have to do that, I just want it to create one by itself, and permanently fix this problem.